# Twitter account authenetication in python with access token

Tags: python, twitter

I have a Web Api project that I have already configured to use Facebook & Google authentication.

Facebook and Google both have a way of verifying the access token given on authentication step.

Facebook:
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={0}&access_token={1}", accessToken, appToken

These return the app_id or consumer key for my applications.

What is the process for Twitter?

The documentation I have read isn't very clear and what I have tried fails and returns a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has nothing for verifying *any* access token similar to the Facebook request you site.

You can only get information about an already authenticated account. You would use [account/verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials). However, this endpoint does not return information about your Twitter application.